# When using RecyclerView in NestedScrollView , how should i set the height of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I have tested that recycler will not in use and RecyclerView will load all data when RecyclerView is `wrap_content` or `match_parent` .

Comment: whats your question??

Comment: When using RecyclerView in NestedScrollView,how to set the height of RecyclerView? `wrap_content`  or  `match_parent` or fixed value ？

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NestedScrollView` instead of `ScrollView` when you're trying to scroll another view in your parent layout.

It's very similar to ScrollView and part of the v4 support lib:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html

Answer (score -1):

Use `setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(Listview listview)` method to set the height of the `ListView` inside the `ScrollView`:  it will make your `ListView` to match parent's height.